# Access the localhost of a Wireguard peer from the local host from another peer?

Tags: wireguard

I have two peers in Wireguard -- A and B. A has a service running on `127.0.0.1:2001`. I want to connect A and B, so that B can access that service on `127.0.0.1:2001` as well. Alternatively, I want to forward `127.0.0.1` to a peer -- however, adding `127.0.0.1/32` to `AllowedIPs` does not work (at least on MacOS).

Comment: You need to set up SSH tunneling for this.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen SSH Tunneling does not offer ranges.

Comment: Especially since I want to port forward everything from `2001-65535`.

Comment: I can use a SOCKS proxy, but it wouldn't be global.

Answer (score 0):

Get the IP of peer B within Wireguard, then on peer A you can connect in its browser just to the IP of peer B. Should work since you're connected through Wireshark.

Comment: Yes, but I want to access it on my localhost.

Comment: What's stopping B accessing the service on the internal IP instead, e.g. `192.168.1.2:2001`?

Comment: @shearn89 Because it's not connected to that IP, only `127.0.0.1` on A, also, it doesn't allow me to access it on `127.0.0.1` on B.

Comment: Would it not make sense to have peer A run the service on the wireguard interface? Then B can access it over WG?

Comment: Binding to the Wireguard interface is the only sensible solution, anything else to access localhost from remote hosts is a hack and quite frankly, a terrible idea.